# Return the start of a email domain

Tags: email, formula

I'm looking for a formula to help return the below from an email domain.

> Email domain: xyzcompany.co.uk
>
> Return: "xyzcompany"

Formula I have gives me the mid and returns "co."

```
MID(
Email_Domain__c,
FIND(".", Email_Domain__c)+1,
FIND(".",
RIGHT( Email_Domain__c , LEN(Email_Domain__c) - FIND(".", Email_Domain__c))
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using this formular:

```
LEFT(Email_Domain__c, FIND(".", Email_Domain__c) - 1)
```

it returns everything before the first dot. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes thank you so much